# Mamp mysql-server stopped working

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

I've been using mamp for a few days now. On both occurences, after a day or two the MYSQL-light turned red and wont go back to green. None of the pages are working.

I tried reinstalling and it worked for a while, but now the issue is back again, on reinstall I used apptrapp to remove config files etc..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i was stuck too but i got the way to fix it and it worked

1 - Quit MAMP
2 - Open the terminal and type: killall -9 mysqld
3 - Restart MAMP

hope it works with you

Answer (score 0):

In my instance, is was SQL that was hanging. For some reason it was never actually shut down, when I stopped the server the previos time. If you go to activity monitor, search for sql ans quit the process, you should then be able to restart MAMP.